# PHP global variable inside class function

Tags: php, class, variables, global

How come inside a function which is inside a class, I can't do this statement:

```
global $connected = true;
```

But I can do this:

```
global $connected;
$connected = true;
```

Comment: I suggest  $GLOBALS associative array with the name of the global variable being the key and the contents of that variable being the value of the array element.

Comment: to clarify there is no problem, I'm just wondering why I can't do it in one statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bringing of `$connected` into scope, and the assignment of a value to it, are two *separate* things.

There is no reason for them to be possible in one statement, which wouldn't really make much sense.

---

Does the following code:

```
function foo() {
   global $x = 5;
}
```

- Bring the "global expression" `$x = 5` into scope?
- Bring the "global expression" `5` into scope?
- Assign `5` to the global `$x`?
- Assign `5` to the global `$x` and then bring `$x` into scope?

I know of course that you intend for it to mean the latter, and that the first two have no meaning. But, that is not clear from the proposed statement. It would be poor syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Because inside a function you first have to announce a global variable. It is something you must do in the beginning of the function. That way you can activate a certain variable which was not passed through.

Comment: Whilst true, this merely states the facts as the OP already knows. It does not attempt to explain _why_ these facts are so.

Comment: Simply put, "because" is not an answer.